# Convert latin1 characters on a UTF8 table into UTF8 Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, symfony

I have UTF-8 data that was originally stored as Latin-1 and then not converted correctly to UTF-8 I also tried to use this code :

```
convert(cast(convert(name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

it works fine for me but at the level of the database MySQL, I need to execute a similar code but using PHP

Comment: Why do you need the PHP version? Once the database is updated to be correct wouldn't the PHP work off of proper UTF8?

Comment: @ChrisHaas the database that I'm working on is already used by another framework application that i can't access and I need to work on the same database without changing it to utf8

Comment: It's not really clear from your description _what_ state your data is in, and I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to reverse-engineer what the SQL solution is doing, but fundamentally, you need to tell a function _what encoding you have_, and _what encoding you want_. PHP has several: [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) from the "mbstring" extension; [UConverter::transcode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/uconverter.transcode.php) from the "intl" extension; or [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) from the "iconv" extension

Comment: Can you elaborate on `not converted correctly to UTF-8`. Do you mean the data is actually corrupt?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do the conversion; most of them are wrong.  First, let's find out how the data is stored -- please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT HEX(col) ...` for some short non-ascii text.